# Reason for Objects static methods in Java 7

Tags: java, java-7

It seems that with Java 7, `Objects` class is providing a lot of functionality already covered in other parts of the language.

Take `toString()` for example. The following will produce the same results:

```
Objects.toString(12);
String.valueOf(12);
```

In fact, `Objects.toString` is defined as:

```
public static String toString(Object o) {
    return String.valueOf(o);
}
```

Say we're dealing with actual classes. Is one preferred over another?

```
Objects.toString(o);
o.toString();
```

What are language designers telling us here? Should we start preferring Objects's solution instead of what's already available? What is a long term rationale for something like this?

Comment: Try that with a non-wrapper class.  The `toString()` you get will be *radically* different (and you won't be able to use `valueOf()`.

Comment: Yeah...it seems to me that use of the Objects static methods is actually moving away from an object-oriented design.  On the other hand, deepEquals seems very useful.

Comment: @CosmicComputer I agree completely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [the documentation for said class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html):

> This class consists of `static` utility methods for operating on objects. These utilities include `null`-safe or `null`-tolerant methods for computing the hash code of an object, returning a string for an object, and comparing two objects.

So it's mostly to save you from an additional `null` guard.